# I've been having trouble making a volume bar using pynput.keyboard

Tags: python, keyboard, volume, pynput

Good day everyone, I am Kurt lee, 9 years old and I would like to ask how can I manage to fix this volume bar using pynput keyboard.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
from ctypes import cast, POINTER
from comtypes import CLSCTX_ALL
from pycaw.pycaw import AudioUtilities, IAudioEndpointVolume



def volume_controller(control):  #
    devices = AudioUtilities.GetSpeakers()
    interface = devices.Activate(IAudioEndpointVolume._iid_, CLSCTX_ALL, None)
    volume = cast(interface, POINTER(IAudioEndpointVolume))
    vol = volume.SetMasterVolumeLevel(control, None)
    return vol

# Volume Bar
VolumeMax = "▁ ▂ ▃ ▄ ▅ ▆ █ 100%" + str(volume_controller(-0))
# Volume86 = "▁ ▂ ▃ ▄ ▅ ▆ 86%" + str(volume_controller(-2.3))
# Volume72 = "▁ ▂ ▃ ▄ ▅ 72%" + str(volume_controller(-5))
# Volume58 = "▁ ▂ ▃ ▄ 58%" + str(volume_controller(-8))
# Volume44 = "▁ ▂ ▃ 44%" + str(volume_controller(-12.2))
# Volume30 = "▁ ▂ 30%" + str(volume_controller(-17.9))
# Volume16 = "▁ 16%" + str(volume_controller(-26.5))
VolumeZero = "Muted" + str(volume_controller(-60))


def check_key(key):
    keyword = key
    if keyword is Key.up:
        print('UP')
        print(VolumeMax)

    elif keyword is Key.down:
        print("Down")
        VolumeZero


# Collect events until released
with Listener(on_press=check_key) as l:
    l.join()
```

I've been having trouble fixing this for a week and I badly need help please. For example, my current volume is 100% which is the Volume max, and I would like to lower it to 86% by clicking down then the next one is to go up to 100% or lower to 72%.

Comment: It might be easier to use a list to store the volume values?

Comment: Is it possible sir? I'm still having trouble making my own volume controller via console